# Android UI with collection of shapes/areas that can detect touch events

Tags: android, events, user-interface, touch, polygons

Background: 
I am doing a research project and am required to create a complex UI that is composed of a collection of odd shapes (i.e. not rectangles or circles, it would be best described as polygons). The complexity is that user interactions (i.e. touch events) should select/deselect individual areas, which can sometimes be very small. And selecting an area should change the color of that specific area!

So the requirement would be to draw a collection of shapes and detect if a touch event falls within the bounds of ones of the shapes/areas and identify which area it is.

If anyone has any idea's or pointers as to where I could start with this, please advice!

Many Thanks!

Comment: You would start out with a Canvas, and drawing your list of objects on it. Then, attach an onClickListener and a onTouchListener to each of them, and report back ;)

There isn't anything 'handy' you can use, so you need to do this the old AWT way - drawing it yourself.

Comment: @Shark: The problem with this approach is the shapes are not rectangular. Defining a rectangular view would create overlaps that would introduce ambiguity when detecting which area was touched! Also, this method seems highly inefficient as either the whole canvas will need to be redrawn on selection or all coordinates would need to be held in memory